# PostgreSQL query with unnest returns no result row for null values

Tags: postgresql, unnest

I am trying to query the values that divides comma separated values in a column as different records ,I could not get the values if the column has null values, Below is the example

Table name: test

```
id,name,list
1,a, a1,b1
2,b, null
3,c,c1
```

Query which is used

```
select id,name,unnest(string_to_array(list,',')) from test;
```

Result:

```
1,a,a1
1,a,b1
3,c,c1
```

But I need to consider the  null values and return the result as below ,I tried using coalesce but that did not work, kindly help me out with the solution

Expected result:

```
1,a,a1
1,a,b1
2,b,null
3,c,c1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `unnest()` with an outer join:

```
select t.id, t.name, u.element 
from test t
  left join unnest(string_to_array(t.list,',')) on true
order by t.id;
```

Comment: I would like to know if i have an outer already there in my sql query select id,name,unnest(string_to_array(list,',')) from test t INNER JOIN test1 t1 on t.id = t1.id ;  where t1.id is foreign key of test table id column

Comment: @Karthikeyan: no. The `unnest()` in the SELECT list, is equivalent to a `cross join` which is similar to an inner join as it does not return rows if the unnest() is empty